# Arduino Nano: This schematic would work?

Tags: arduino, power, servo

If I used this 9v battery, and a 6v battery pack(AA battery), would this combination work.
I want to it run disconnected from the PC.

[image]

Sorry my bad english.

Comment: It is unclear what Arduino pins connect where. Consider creating a proper circuit diagram with the built in circuit editor (try hitting Ctrl-M). Use `custom part` as your Arduino and label the pins accordingly. Same can be used for your server, with lesser pins. Use `Voltage source` for your batteries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That should work as long as your Servo motor is rated 6V power (each battery cell contributes 1.5V). The key thing is that the battery pack GNDs be connected together. The servo motor responds to a variable pulse width signal. The Nano will output 5V digital I/O. The servo should be responsive to PWM at those levels, but as always check it's datasheet for maximum limits (or provide a link and we can help).

Comment: Thank you. The power is all right, my doubt was about the GND wires. Now, it's solved.